# Issue in deleting folders and files using msbuild

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, msbuild

I am trying to delete some files and folders excluding few files using msbuild.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionName>TestProject</SolutionName>
    <SolutionFileName>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/$(SolutionName).sln</SolutionFileName>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <BuildVersion Condition="'$(BuildVersion)' == ''">1.0.0.0</BuildVersion>      <BuildTargetFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\TestProjectBuild</BuildTargetFolder>
    <OutputPath>$(BuildTargetFolder)\Builds\$(Configuration)\TestProject - $(BuildVersion)</OutputPath>    
  </PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CleanDirExludeFinalOutput">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Item to get all files recursively in the DeleteRoot folder -->
      <FilesToDelete Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*.*" Exclude="$(OutputPath)\**\*.msi;$(OutputPath)\**\*.exe"/>
      <!-- Item to get all folders from the files to be deleted -->
      <FoldersToDelete Include="%(FilesToDelete.RootDir)%(FilesToDelete.Directory)" Exclude="$(OutputPath)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <!-- Display what will be deleted -->
    <Message Text=" # @(FilesToDelete)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" # @(FoldersToDelete)" Importance="high" />

    <!-- Delete the files -->
    <Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" Condition=" $(OutputPath)!=''" ContinueOnError="true"/>
    <!-- Remove the folders -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(FoldersToDelete)" Condition="$(OutputPath)!=''" />
  </Target>
```

Now when I am trying to run the above script using msbuild command from the VisualStudio2010 CommandPrompt I see all the files are deleted. I don't want to delete the TestProject.msi,setup.exe.

The above works fine if I set

```
<BuildTargetFolder>C:\temp\TestProjectBuild</BuildTargetFolder>
```

All the files and folders are deleted with the exception of TestProject.msi,setup.exe

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?